# Python Calendar Leap Year Function Code Not Working

Tags: python, function, calendar

So I am currently trying to create a function whereby when you input a specific year and calendar.isleap(year) will then process whether that year is a leap year with True or False.

My issue is I can't seem to figure out a function whereby it will decide whether the year input is True of False and will then print out that year along with a string. The example I have created and tried to use is below:

```
import calendar

def leap_year():
    year = calendar.isleap(year)
    if calendar.isleap == True:
        print(year + 'is a leap year')
    else:
        print(year + 'is not a leap year')

year = 2016

leap_year()
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `isleap()` method returns `True` if the year is a leap year, otherwise `False`.

```
import calendar
print(calendar.isleap(2016))
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes, you need to pass in the year to the function and have "year" as a variable in your function, and then cast the year to a string when printing.

```
import calendar

def leap_year(year):
    if calendar.isleap(year) == True:
        print(str(year) + ' is a leap year')
    else:
        print(str(year) + ' is not a leap year')

leap_year(2016)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code could have been

```
def leap_year(check_year):
    if ((check_year%4==0)and not(check_year%100==0))or (check_year%400==0)  :
        print(str(year) + 'is a leap year')
    else:
        print(str(year) + 'is not a leap year')

year = 2016

leap_year(year)
```

Comment: Why replace a perfectly valid use of `calendar.isleap` with an untested reimplementation?

Comment: Because by using calender.isleap there is no use of declaring a function then

Comment: Sure there is; you're still printing a custom message based on result.

Comment: You could have also done that without using the function

Comment: The main purpose of using the isleap method is to lessen the need for a function like this

Comment: But your replacement doesn't affect the need for `leap_year` *at all*. Whether you use a tested library function or your custom expression, you still have the conditional that outputs an message rather than simply returning True or False. The expression masks the real gain, which was to eliminate the local/global collision (and the need to test the result of `isleap` correctly), by adding a function parameter and eliminating the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. First, your function creates a new *local* variable named `year` that shadows the global variable. Due to how name lookup works, you can't pass the global variable `year` to `calendar.isleap` and assign the result to the local variable. Use a different name for the local variable. Second, you want to see if the *result* of `calendar.isleap` is `True`, not the function itself. Use your new local variable in the expression.

```
def leap_year():
    result = calendar.isleap(year)
    if result == True:
        print(str(year) + 'is a leap year')
    else:
        print(str(year) + 'is not a leap year')
```

As a matter of style, don't compare a boolean variable to a boolean constant; just testing the variable directly:

```
if result:
    print(year + 'is a leap year')
```

This means that you don't even *need* the local variable; just use the function call directly in the `if` statement:

```
def leap_year():
    if calendar.isleap(year):
        print(year + 'is a leap year')
    else:
        print(year + 'is not a leap year')
```

Finally, using a global variable here is bad style. Instead, pass they year to check as an *argument* to `leap_year`.

```
def leap_year(y):
    if calendar.isleap(y):
        print(str(y) + 'is a leap year')
    else:
        print(str(y) + 'is not a leap year')

year = 2016
leap_year(year)  # Or simply leap_year(2016)
```